# Cannot add a user to lock pages in memory group policy to enable AWE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, awe

We are trying to enable AWE on Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00 running on a Windows Server 2003 R2.

After following this post http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190730.aspx we go to the group policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Setting -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Lock pages in memory -> Add User or Group.

But the area (Add User or Group) is disable.

[image]

The user I'm using belongs to the group: domain administrator, enterprise admin, etc. privilege

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the user by the command prompt with the tool NTRIGHTS.